# Помощь с процентами, питон

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
queries = [
'смотреть сериалы онлайн',
'новости спорта',
'афиша кино',
'курс доллара',
'сериалы этим летом',
'курс по питону',
'сериалы про спорт',
'один',
'два',
'три',
'sdf'

]

res = [(x,len(x.split())) for x in queries]
res1 = dict(res)

count3 = 0 
count2 = 0
count1 = 0
for i in res1.values():
  if i == 3:

    count3 += 1
  elif i == 2:
    count2 += 1
  elif i == 1:
    count1 += 1


print(f'Запросы с 3-мя словами составляют: { count3 * 10} %') 
print(f'Запросы с 2-мя словами составляют: {count2 * 10} %')
print(f'Запросы с 1-им словом составляют: {count1 * 10} %')
```

Мне нужно ответы перевести в проценты, т,е. я получаю данные о количестве слов в каждом элементе и вывожу, а теперь мне надо перевести это в процент , но я не доконца понимаю как это сделать(то есть проценты я как бы считать умею) но я не понимаю мне queries принять за сто процентов и отнимать необходимое и как тогда это реализовывать ? Памагити

Comment: процент __чего__ вы хотите посчитать?

Comment: Процент этих значений от списка queries

Comment: мне незнакомо понятие "процент от списка" - можете пояснить? А еще лучше - добавить текст оригинального задания в  вопрос

Comment: `count = [count1, count2, count3]; 100 * count[i] / sum(count)`. Если считать через `queries`, то `100 * count1 / len(queries)`

Comment: 100% это что? Общее количество слов или количество элементов в списке?

Answer (score 0):

```py
queries = [
    'смотреть сериалы онлайн',
    'новости спорта',
    'афиша кино',
    'курс доллара',
    'сериалы этим летом',
    'курс по питону',
    'сериалы про спорт',
    'один',
    'два',
    'три',
    'sdf'
]

lq = len(queries)

words = dict()

for query in queries:
    l = len(query.split())
    words[l] = words.setdefault(l, 0) + 1

print(f'Запросы с 3-мя словами составляют: {lq / 100 * words[3]} %')
print(f'Запросы с 2-мя словами составляют: {lq / 100 * words[2]} %')
print(f'Запросы с 1-им словом составляют: {lq / 100 * words[1]} %')
```

Comment: А почему использован `.setdefault`, а не `.get`? Я честно говоря до сих пор не до конца разницу понимаю

Comment: @CrazyElf, Если честно, очень очень давно кто-то показал так. С тех пор привык, теперь пишу так. Не вижу тоже